# How to reverse roles of TcpListener/TcpClient?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener, system.net.sockets

I have an unusual question that I hope to get input on. I'm new to network programming and am learning socket programming via the .NET "TcpListener" and "TcpClient" classes in the System.Net.Sockets namespace. I need to use them in an unusual manner though: I need to be able to establish a connection between computer A and computer B. Computer A will be running an instance of the "TcpClient" class and will attempt to open a connection to computer B which is running an instance of "TcpListener". This part seems straight forward. However, once the connection has been established I need to reverse the roles so that computer A becomes the machine that waits for and responds to messages sent from computer B. In other words computer A then becomes the server and computer B becomes the client. This role reversal must use the same connection that was opened by computer A when it was initially acting as a client. It's not clear to me how to do this as all the examples and the (excellent) book "TCP/IP Sockets in C#" I'm reading always use these classes in their predefined roles. Is there actually a way to do this? Do I have to drop down to the "Socket" class rather than use the more abstracted "TcpListener/TcpClient" classes?

Comment: There's no difference in the way the messages are handled, just the way the connection is established.  Once the socket is open either client or server can send/receive messages.

Comment: I don't think that you need to reverse roles. Just when your Client receive message he will send response and wait for next message. The same will do the Listener but he will wait for response and send next message.